# What do Network In and Network Out mean in Amazon?

Tags: networking, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch

If you got an instance with 10 Gigabit Ethernet. What does it mean? How much bytes do you have in Network In and how much in Network Out as maximum?

In the reports of Cloud Watch I can see 80,000,000 in Network In, and 800,000,000 in Network Out. When it is coming close to 120,000,000 in Network In the site starts to load slow and some pictures or assets don't load. Is it the maximum?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

1. 10 Gigabit Ethernet, assume it is full duplex, so maximum Network In=max Network Out = 10 Gbps / 8 = 1.25 GB/second.

Gbps: Gigabit per second; GB: Giga Byte; MB: Mega Byte

2. Cloud Watch, 80,000,000 in Network In means 80MB per 60 seconds.
   120,000,000 in Network In => 120MB / 60s => 2 MB/s  => 16 Mbps, it far from the maxium 100 Mbps. But it still depend on what instance type you use.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/viewing_metrics_with_cloudwatch.html
https://www.datadoghq.com/blog/why-do-aws-cloudwatch-and-datadog-seem-to-disagree/

Comment: I'm pretty sure that 80,000,000 in NetworkIn means different things depending on whether you have detailed metrics enabled.  I think it's literally just the number of bytes sent since the last metric value was recorded.  So if you don't have detailed metrics enabled, it means 80MiB in 5 minutes, or 2.03 Mbps averaged across the 5 minute measurement period.

Comment: According to AWS support,  it is always per 1 minute, even if your granularity is 5 minute periods.

Comment: @GarrGodfrey From the docs referenced above: "The number reported is the number of bytes received during the period. If you are using basic (five-minute) monitoring, you can divide this number by 300 to find Bytes/second. If you have detailed (one-minute) monitoring, divide it by 60." Looks like it's per 5 minute for 5 minute periods

Comment: Even the detailed monitoring not enabled, the sampling frequency is one minute, so there are 5 values in the 5-minute period. The different types of statistics (Minimum, Maximum, Average, Sum) applied to these 5 values. The Sum statistics always is equal to the 5 * Average statistics. This means, you have to divide by 60 for the Minimum, Maximum and Average statistics and you have to divide by 300 for the Sum statistics (to get per second logic). The AWS docs link above, doesn't tell, which statistics is used. In the second link, Average statistics is used.